# How to get an Exception source object

Tags: java, exception

I was working on an assigment in Java, and I wondered if it's possible to know which object throwed an exception.

I know that if you make your custom exceptions, you can modify the constructor and have a reference to the object:

```
public class MyEx extends Throwable {
    private MyObject object;

    public MyEx(MyObject o){
        super();
    }

    public MyObject getSource(){
        return object;
    }
}
```

but I don't know if there exists another way of catching who throwed the exception. Do you know any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to see from which part of the code an exception is thrown, you have the simple stack trace. You get this by calling `printStackTrace()` on an exception instance.

This does not however give you the exact object instance that threw the exception. For this you have to implement a custom Exception like you indicated. Note that in some contexts there is no such thing as an instance, like e.g. an exception thrown from a static method.

Comment: You can also use exception.getStackTrace() if you want to do more with the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle's exception(s) tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

and

[Java2s Examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/0360__Exception.htm)